# Can I reserve a place for id in SQL Server on form load

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms

I have retrieved the last ID incremented by 1 into a textbox on form load, but is there a way to reserve a place in the table for this ID (that is retrieved), until form is saved?? Because there are multi users using this form and i need to get an ID once form is loaded, although form might take more time to be saved.
Am using c# for my application,i don't know if i have to implement this on my code application or in database itself.

Comment: Do you mind about the sequence?

Comment: why don't you use auto incremented Id generated by SQL server itself ?

Comment: No i don't mind  Saeed Hamed

Comment: form may take several hours to be saved ,in that time users may save several forms ,and i need to get that ID from the first

Answer (score 1):

You can change the current value of identity column by executing the following code

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ([TableName], RESEED, 50)
```

But keep in mind that for inserting your record you must first set **IDENTITY_INSERT** on and then set it off like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName] ([Id], [Title]) VALUES  ( 50 , '123' )

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableName] OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the row with minimal data and then update record when form is saved. You need to add a flag to mark invalid condition on data of this row. Maybe you need to clean up records marked as invalid periodically.

Another possible solution is create an aux table to store generated IDs but maybe, you must add additional information to know which is the origin, i.e., a reference to form.

Comment: "save the row with minimal data " ; you mean that some columns will have null values until form is saved ?

Comment: Just putting something into (the actual table/a separate table) as suggested here is far better than some form of "reservation" within the session - because such a reservation would undoubtedly imply that a transaction be held open for the entire length of time that the reservation applies for. In general, try to keep transactions *short*.

Comment: Well, am thinking of using a view, saving the ID in it and reusing it when form is saved then it is deleted when from the view.. is that way safe??

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it's not on a transaction scope, you can close your transaction as you marked data as invalid/incomplete. When you want to save complete data simply update the incomplete record and mark as valid/complete.

Comment: @TonyG.Bolaño - my point was that this answer does avoid needing a transaction scope. Whereas any solution (that the OP was hinting at) that just holds the value "reserved" and not actually committed in the database *would* require a long running transaction.

Comment: @R.JN Data saves on tables, not views. You can have an "updatable" view, but data stores in tables

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's the point, you commit to database marking data as invalid (if use the final table) or simply commit to an aux table that holds reserved IDs. No long transactions here. You even can close database connection. When you has final data then commit changes to database (update or insert in final table).

Comment: @TonyG.Bolaño - we're violently agreeing with each other here, and have been right from my first comment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree, I'm confused by "reservation within the session" (it's not a premise in original question). ;)

Comment: @Tony G. Bolaño yeah it worked with i have created a table incidentNoReserve and bring Id from incidentNo then saves it in IncidentNoreserve ,then when saving ,it saves that id in incidentNo then deletes it from incidentNoReserve

Comment: @R.JN Glad to help